# PowerShell regex -match only matching once

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to run through files named using alphabetical dates, and set file date-times accordingly. My code works fine, and I was ready to consider it complete, when I noticed this issue. My code should detect two dates and generate an error, but it doesn't. I've extracted the relevant code, and recreated the issue:

```
$str = "test20001231 20170415.txt"
$match = ($str -match "(?<=\b|\D)20\d{6,6}(?=\b|\D)")
"$match"
"$($Matches.length)"
"$($Matches[0].ToString())"
```

Gives this output:

```
True
1
20001231
```

My understanding of the regex code is that it should match everything that is an 8 digit number beginning with 20, wherever it is in the string, unless it is following or preceding another digit. So I am expecting $Matches.length to be 2.

I've tested the regex code in a number of places online, and it matches the two dates as I expect: 
http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cb%7c%5cD%2920%5cd%7b6%2c6%7d%28%3f%3d%5cb%7c%5cD%29&i=test20001231+20170415.txt
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jLA

The issue applies to PS and PS ISE. I've searches lots (I think), and not turned up anything helpful.
Any suggestions?
Many thanks in advance,
Dave

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**PowerShell's `-match` operator only ever looks for the *first* match (if any) per input string**, because its purpose is to *test* for *a* (any) match, irrespective of whether there is more than one.

<sup>Note that a single `-match` expression can have *multiple* input strings, if the LHS is an *array*, in which case an *array of the elements that match* is returned; e.g.: `'foo', 'bar', 'baz' -match 'b'` yields array `'bar', 'baz'`. However, for each array *element* only a *single* match is again tested for, and the automatic `$Matches` variables is *not* populated in this case - see bottom.</sup>

<sup>All commands below assume PSv3+, but could be made to work in v2 too.</sup>

You need to **use the .NET framework's [`[regex]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.aspx) class to get *multiple* matches**:

```powershell
PS> ([regex]::Matches('test20001231 20170415.txt', '(?<=\b|\D)20\d{6,6}(?=\b|\D)')).Value
20001231
20170415
```

`[regex]::Matches()` outputs a collection of [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) instances<sup>[1]</sup> whose `.Value` properties contain the matches.

<sup>Note how `.Value` is applied to the entire *collection*, which in PSv3+
automatically returns the property values of the collection *members* as an array.</sup>

To get just the *count* of matches:

```powershell
PS> ([regex]::Matches('test20001231 20170415.txt', '(?<=\b|\D)20\d{6,6}(?=\b|\D)')).Count
2
```

---

**Another option is to use `Select-String -AllMatches`**, which outputs `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]` instances
whose `.Matches` property contains each line's collection of `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]` instances:

```powershell
PS> ('test20001231 20170415.txt' |
    Select-String -AllMatches '(?<=\b|\D)20\d{6,6}(?=\b|\D)').Matches.Value
20001231
20170415
```

As above, substituting `.Count` for `.Value` outputs the number of matches.

Note that use of **`Select-String` is a bit heavy-handed for use with a single input string**, but it's **the right tool to use for large input collections**, such as a file's lines.

---

**Optional reading: The automatic `$Matches` variable:**

The automatic `$Matches` variable is populated (as of PSv5.1):

- *only* when you use the `-match` operator
- *and* the LHS is a *scalar*

  - by contrast, with an *array* on the LHS, `$Matches` is neither populated nor reset.
- *and* a match is found (`-match` returns `$true`)

  - if *no* match is found (`-match` returns `$false`), a preexisting `$Matches` value, if any, is left untouched.

`$Matches` is a `[hashtable]` instance with the following entries:

- key `0`'s entry is the entire match - this key is by definition always present.
- key `<n>`'s entry is what the - unnamed - capture group with index `<n>` matched.
- key `<name>`'s entry is what *named* capture group `<name>` matched.

The fact that `$Matches` (potentially) also contains capture-group values justifies its *plural* name - despite only relating to a *single* match of the given regex.

---

<sup>[1] To inspect the type of a single object or the type of the elements of a collection, pipe to [Get-Member](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member): `([regex]::Matches('foo', 'o')) | Get-Member`

To inspect the type of a collection *itself*, pass it to `Get-Member -InputObject`:

`Get-Member -InputObject ([regex]::Matches('foo', 'o'))`</sup>